# Are 10GBASE-T ethernet magnetics modules compatible with 1000BASE-T?

Tags: ethernet, magnetics

I am designing a board with a 1000BASE-T ethernet PHY and I want to use a discrete magnetics module since I will be using a non-standard connector.

However, I am constrained with space and I found a magnetics module for 10GBASE-T with a pretty small footprint ([HM7142NL](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pulse-electronics/HM7142NL/10445503)), probably because of the smaller open circuit inductance. Will this work with 1000BASE-T?

Where can I find the specifications for this? I tried navigating the IEEE802.3, but it is a bit daunting.

Edit:
I am using the [VSC8501XML-03](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/vsc8501) PHY, I tried looking for magnetics specifications in the datasheet but haven't found them, maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I am using the [VSC8501XML-03](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/vsc8501), I tried looking for magnetics specifications in the datasheet but haven't found them, maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @MatiasB please edit the question and add the information there ... do not add information in comments